# pyspark cumulative count distinct

Tags: pyspark

I want to produce a daily cumulative count of unique visitors to a website, and pyspark countDistinct native function doesn't work inside a moving/growing window

For the following data:

```
+---+----+
|day|user|
+---+----+
|  1|   A|
|  2|   B|
|  3|   A|
|  4|   C|
|  5|   C|
|  5|   B|
+---+----+
```

would expect the result:

```
+---+---------+
|day|cum_count|
+---+---------+
|  1|        1| -> [A]
|  2|        2| -> [A,B]
|  3|        2| -> [A,B]
|  4|        3| -> [A,B,C]
|  5|        3| -> [A,B,C]
+---+---------+
```

PS: The original data is huge and can't be dumped to pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could achieve this result transforming the problem from a cumulative count distinct to a cumulative sum. The catch was to keep only the first user visit in the period.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

#example dataset
>>> data = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'A'],[4,'C'],[5,'C'],[5,'B']],schema=['day','user'])
>>> data.show()
+---+----+
|day|user|
+---+----+
|  1|   A|
|  2|   B|
|  3|   A|
|  4|   C|
|  5|   C|
|  5|   B|
+---+----+

#enumerate each user visit
>>> data = data.withColumn('user_visit',F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('user').orderBy('day')))
>>> data.orderBy('user','day').show()
+---+----+----------+
|day|user|user_visit|
+---+----+----------+
|  1|   A|         1|
|  3|   A|         2|
|  2|   B|         1|
|  5|   B|         2|
|  4|   C|         1|
|  5|   C|         2|
+---+----+----------+

#Keep just the first visit
>>> data = data.withColumn('first_visit',F.when(F.col('user_visit') == 1,1))
>>> data.orderBy('day','user').show()
+---+----+----------+-----------+
|day|user|user_visit|first_visit|
+---+----+----------+-----------+
|  1|   A|         1|          1|
|  2|   B|         1|          1|
|  3|   A|         2|       null|
|  4|   C|         1|          1|
|  5|   B|         2|       null|
|  5|   C|         2|       null|
+---+----+----------+-----------+

# cumulative sum of first visits
>>> w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('day').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0)
>>> data = data.withColumn('cum_count',F.sum('first_visit').over(w))
>>> data.orderBy('day','user').show()
+---+----+----------+-----------+---------+
|day|user|user_visit|first_visit|cum_count|
+---+----+----------+-----------+---------+
|  1|   A|         1|          1|        1|
|  2|   B|         1|          1|        2|
|  3|   A|         2|       null|        2|
|  4|   C|         1|          1|        3|
|  5|   B|         2|       null|        3|
|  5|   C|         2|       null|        3|
+---+----+----------+-----------+---------+

#aditional step to get the day total without duplicates
>>> data.groupBy('day').agg(F.max('cum_count')).show()
+---+--------------+
|day|max(cum_count)|
+---+--------------+
|  1|             1|
|  2|             2|
|  3|             2|
|  4|             3|
|  5|             3|
+---+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

A shorter solution which collects unique users using `collect_set` and retrieves its length using `size`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

cum_count = F.size(
    F.collect_set(F.col('user'))
     .over(Window.orderBy('day').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
).alias('cum_count')

df.select('day', cum_count)
df.show()
    
+---+---------+
|day|cum_count|
+---+---------+
|  1|        1|
|  2|        2|
|  3|        2|
|  4|        3|
|  5|        3|
|  5|        3|
+---+---------+
```

Comment: That is a nice solution, but it didn't work for large datasets

Comment: @Maviles Well, you didn't specify that you're working on a large dataset in your question when I answered it